# SQL dynamic query with synonym

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is this possible,
Its not working!!
Trying to acheive execution

```
Declare @SQL as varchar(1000)

Set @SQL =  'Select ''create synonym syn_'' + t.name + '' for ['' +   
DB_NAME() + ''].[''+ s.name + ''].['' + t.name + '']''

from sys.tables t
    inner join sys.schemas s
        on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.type = ''U'' and t.name in 

(''Episode'',''MasterNPI'',''Patient'',''Enterprises'')'

Print @SQL
```

Comment: mind telling us what this is actually trying to do, and what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You completely got it wrong. You query will just execute the `select` query, it will not create `synonym`.

Here is what you are looking for

```
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(1000) 

SET @sql = (SELECT ' create synonym syn_' + t.NAME + ' for ' 
                   + Quotename(Db_name()) + '.' + Quotename(s.NAME) 
                   + '.' + Quotename(t.NAME) + ' ; ' 
            FROM   sys.tables t 
                   INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
                           ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
            WHERE  t.type = 'U' 
                   AND t.NAME IN ( 'Episode', 'MasterNPI', 'Patient', 
                                   'Enterprises' ) 
            FOR xml path('')) 

EXEC(@SQL)
```